# Graphing different variables in the same graph R- ggplot2

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr

I have several datasets and my end goal is to do a graph out of them, with each line representing the yearly variation for the given information. I finally joined and combined my data (as it was in a per month structure) into a table that just contains the yearly means for each item I want to graph (column depicting year and subsequent rows depicting yearly variation for 4 different elements)

[image]

I have one factor that is the year and 4 different variables that read yearly variations, thus I would like to graph them on the same space. I had the idea to joint the 4 columns into one by factor (collapse into one observation per row and the year or factor in the subsequent row) but seem unable to do that. My thought is that this would give a structure to my y axis.  Would like some advise, and to know if my approach to the problem is effective. I am trying ggplot2 but does not seem to work without a defined (or a pre defined range) y axis. Thanks

Comment: Can we please have a [mcve]?  That includes editing your question to post a useful part of your data set as *text* (e.g. using `dput()`) rather than a screenshot ...

Comment: I am terribly sorry for my rough approach, I will have it in mind for a next and more experienced post

Comment: You don't need to apologize, or wait!  You can edit this question (and get upvotes instead of downvotes ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest next approach. You have to reshape your data from wide to long as next example. In that way is possible to see all variables. As no data is provided, this solution is sketched using dummy data. Also, you can change lines to other geom you want like points:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
#Data
df <- data.frame(year=1990:2000,
                 v1=rnorm(11,2,1),
                 v2=rnorm(11,3,2),
                 v3=rnorm(11,4,1),
                 v4=rnorm(11,5,2))
#Plot
df %>% pivot_longer(-year) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(year),y=value,group=name,color=name))+
  geom_line()+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use `melt` from `reshape2` without loading multiple other packages

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(melt(df, id.var = 'year'), aes(x = factor(year), y = value,
    group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

-output plot

[image]

---

Or with `matplot` from `base R`

```
matplot(as.matrix(df[-1]), type = 'l', xaxt = 'n')
```

#### data

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(year=1990:2000,
                 v1=rnorm(11,2,1),
                 v2=rnorm(11,3,2),
                 v3=rnorm(11,4,1),
                 v4=rnorm(11,5,2))
```